# How to Automatically Restart MySQL Server in the event of Crash?

Tags: mysql

I can't restored by simply restarting the MySQL server and this could reduce a lot your website downtime.

My version is MySql 5.5.62 and SO is Windows 7.

I have tried this VBS Script without success, because reply with error string **Program Files** is not valid.

```
   Function DblQuote(Str)
      DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
   End Function

   serviceName = "MySQL"

   Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
   state = wmi.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & serviceName & "'").State

   SQL_CMD = "cmd /k "& DblQuote("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe") &_
             "--defaults-file="& DblQuote("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini") & " MySQL"        

   If state <> "Running" Then   

      Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

      oShell.run "cmd /k "& DblQuote("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe") &_
                  "--defaults-file="& DblQuote("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini") & " MySQL"   

      Set oShell = Nothing

   End If
   on error goto 0
   Wscript.quit
```

Comment: `sc query mysql80 | find "RUNNING" || sc start mysql80`

Comment: @Akina thanks for reply. Your string must be expected in VB Script file or batch file?

Comment: Batch file, or single command in the action. Test in CMD window.

Comment: @Akina Test in CMD response Access Denied... How can I go about execute the Batch file as Administrator?

Comment: Your account have no enough access rights for service start? test simple `sc start mysql80`...

Comment: @Akina test in CMD simple `sc start mysql80` response Access Denied...

Comment: This is your local problem. Add proper privilege (starting services) to the OS account which this command is executed from (in local policy, for example). Or use RUNAS.